# Power analysis for prospective cohort study

Tags: statistical-power, biostatistics

I am writing a grant proposal for a project which primarily aims to test the association between vaginal microbiota composition and miscarriage in a prospective, population-based cohort of pregnant women in Brazil.

I need to determine the proper sample size when the alpha level is 0.05, power is 80%, and effect size is ideally somewhere between a small-medium effect.

My question is, how can I carry out this power analysis for this type of study? The number of women we derive vaginal samples from will be one aspect of the sample, but then of course, we won't be able to control the number of women who do or do not have a miscarriage, our main outcome of interest.

I would appreciate any advice on this, I so far haven't been able to find a clear answer in my online searches.

Comment: Could you give a quantitative expression of "small-medium effect"?  You might also need to tell us the anticipated miscarriage rates.

Comment: With respect to the effect size, I meant for example a Cohen's d of 0.3 or 0.35, as a medium effect is given as 0.50, and a small effect as 0.20 for this particular effect size index.

Comment: I can do a search to see if I can find some more information on the miscarriage rates in this particular city, or at least the state. But, what if they were, for example, 10%, or 1000 for every 10,000 women?

Comment: If I know the anticipated miscarriage rates, how can I use this information to help me calculate the sample size? Also, if anyone out there has experience specifically with calculating sample size for a study on the microbiota that would be extremely helpful.

Comment: The rates determine the effect size and its sampling variance.  Both of those are key inputs into any power analysis.